# ng-init not working for select tag with ng-options

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a seemingly simple yet frustrating issue getting a default value to populate a select tag on page load. Here is my HTML:

```
<select ng-model="gc.statusType" ng-init="gc.statusType = gc.statusArray[0][1]" ng-options="status[0] as status[1] for status in gc.statusArray"></select>
```

"gc" above is the name of the scoped controller As in the javascript, and gc.statusArray is a 2 dimensional array with each index as another array with a number value at index "0" and the corresponding string descrition at index "1", which I have initialized to have the first index have no number value by making the first index of self.statusArray = [[' ', 'All Statuses']];.

This is the code for the function that populates that array from properties of a more complex object (and I know the array populates correctly):

```
self.fillStatusArray = function() {
   self.statusArray = [['', 'All Statuses']];
   var contentStatus = this.projects.statuses.data;
   for(var x in contentStatus) {
      var statusInt = parseInt(contentStatus[x].id);
      self.statusArray.push([statusInt, contentStatus[x].name])
   }
};
self.fillStatusArray();
```

I want the select tag to have a default of the first index ( [ ' ', 'All Statuses' ] ) on page load. Any idea what I'm doing wrong??

Thanks!

Comment: if `this.projects.statuses.data` going to come by ajax, then your code wouldn't work. Also `ng-init` directive shouldn't be used anywhere in application.. check angular docs for the same. Rather should shift that method call code to controller of respective template

Comment: I actually figured out some other stuff I had wrong, and got my problem solved.. however I still am using ng-init. What do you mean that it should not be used anywhere in the application? Then what is the point of it? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Look [at docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit), actually it was introduced earlier by Angular, but thereafter people are mis-using it in unwanted scenario's